# cplex java api ifThen structure

Tags: java, if-statement, cplex

I am trying to model an constraint in cplex which is of IF-THEN structure. In a 2d-array(m x m+n) i want if the sum_ofRows(m rows) is 1, then the sum_ofColumns(m columns) should be 0 . In cplex java api the IF-THEN structure takes as arguments two constraints cplex.ifThen(Iloconstraint arg0, Iloonstraint arg2). 1) how can i create a constraint without adding it to the model, meaning not using cplex.addEq(1, variable), but to store it somewhere as a constraint? 2)we have an expression and then we add the equality or inequality check and it is automatically added to the model as well, am I right?

```
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
                drArrRow[i] =  cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                        drArrRow[i].addTerm(1, x[i][j]);

                    }
                    cplex.addEq(1, drArrRow[i]);
                }

            //second part "then"
               for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
                   drArrCol[j] =  cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    for(int i=0; i<m;i++){
                        drArrCol[i].addTerm(1, x[i][j]);

                    }
                    cplex.addEq(1, drArrCol[j]);
                }

    //cplex.ifThen(constraint, constraint);
    //Here i got stuck
```

Thank you!

Is this a correct answer??

```
            IloLinearNumExpr[] drArrCol= new IloLinearNumExpr[m];
            IloLinearNumExpr[] drArrRow= new IloLinearNumExpr[m];
            IloConstraint[] drColConstr= new IloConstraint[m];
            IloConstraint[] drRowConstr= new IloConstraint[m];
            // first part "if"  
            for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
                drArrRow[i] =  cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                        drArrRow[i].addTerm(1, x[i][j]);

                    }
                    drColConstr[i] = cplex.eq(1, drArrRow[i]);
                }

            //second part "then"
               for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
                   drArrCol[j] =  cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    for(int i=0; i<m;i++){
                        drArrCol[j].addTerm(1, x[i][j]);

                    }
                    drRowConstr[j] = cplex.eq(1, drArrRow[j]);
                }
             //end of 3 constraint 

               for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
                        cplex.ifThen(drRowConstr[i], drColConstr[i]);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the correct answer. I've used constraints without addint them to the model before and it worked just like you wrote in your code.